# Why is the badge count on top of the page different than the badge count in the profile?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges

I noticed that I recently obtained the "Autobiographer" badge, and three others, and somehow my badge count is still at 8 on the top of the page whereas it correctly displays 12 on my profile. My question may be naive, but why doesn't it show the correct count ?

Is it because of some caching and that it takes some time to update ? 
Is it because some badges are not "considered" enough to be counted in the total number of badges displayed ?

I guess the world will not change tomorrow if I get the answer, but I'm just curious :-)

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a [recent bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104094/new-badges-do-not-update-your-badge-count-when-awarded).

The badge counts were updating yesterday (25th August).

**UPDATE**

The bug has been [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104094/new-badges-do-not-update-your-badge-count-when-awarded/104104#104104), so you should see your badge count correct itself soon.

Comment: Oh, I did not know there is a "meta" site for every stackexchange website. There's just too many things to read :-) Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Jalayn - Meta Stack Overflow is the main meta site for the whole network as well as being the meta for Stack Overflow itself. If you have a question about Programmers ask it here.